# Custom error page on Membership provider DB down

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, database-connection

I use MySql as my RDBMS, providing Membership and Roles in a MVC 4 application. Works just fine. In the case the MySql server is down, it seems MVC tries to redirect to the defaultRedirect page configured in Web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.html">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="Error/PageNotFound" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error/PageNotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

But it renders a standard MVC error page, stating there was an exception in the web app and additionally an exception on the request for the custom error page. The adressbar show this url:

```
http://localhost/WebApp/Views/Shared/Error.html?aspxerrorpath=/WebApp
```

Fiddler shows the 500 status code on the first request. The debugger does not stop on the first line of Application_Start() in Global.asax.cs - it seems the error occurs and is handled on parsing the Web.config. I assume this is done by the web server?

What would be the correct way to handle an unreachable SQL database configured in Web.config and presenting the user with an informative error page?